# convexity of a function and inequality condition

Tags: functions

i have two functions, a quadratic: $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ (where $a>0$, $b<0$, $c>0$), and a linear function: $g(x) = dx + c$ (where $d<0$)

now $f(0)=g(0)=c$

how can i use convexity of $f(x)$ to show $g(x)>f(x)$ in the interval $(0,N]$ if and only if$g(N)>f(N)$?

can i show this for N=1?

i know for convex $f(x)$, $f[Lx1+(1-L)x2] < Lf(x1) + (1-L)f(x2)$, where $0$

thanks

this is for research on a paper on economics, for which i'm doing a presentation, and i've already shown this with figures. i just want to know if i can do this mathematically, then i can insert mathematical explanation, otherwise i will just use my figures.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is convex, then for any points $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ and $\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$ lying above the graph $y=f(x)$, and for any $t\in[0,1],$ we have that $\langle tx_1+(1-t)x_2,ty_1+(1-t)y_2\rangle$ also lies above the graph $y=f(x).$ In particular, we can use this to show that $g(x)>f(x)$ on $(0,N]$ if $g(N)>f(N).$ On the other hand, if $g(x)>f(x)$ on $(0,N],$ then we immediately have $g(N)>f(N).$

Answer (score 0):

Construct the auxiliary function $\phi(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. We have $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi$ is also convex. For the case you are considering $\phi^\prime(0)=2a\cdot 0 - d=-d>0$ and moreover since $\phi$ is convex, $\phi^\prime$ is non-decreasing (in your example it is increasing) so $\phi^\prime>0$ for all $x>0$. That is, $\phi$ is always increasing so: $$\underbrace{f(x)-g(x)}_{=\phi(x)}>\underbrace{f(0)-g(0)}_{=\phi(0)}=0, \quad\forall x>0.$$